# Locating WSL 2 files on a seperate Windows installation

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've got a drive with an old install of Windows + WSL 2. I want to back up the WSL filesystem, but I can't find the files.

For some reason, the only file in `D:\wsl$\` is `D:\wsl$\Arch\home\username\.ssh\config`. Is there some other location where they might be? There's only one partition on the drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's going to be tricky.  The `D:\wsl$\` is *likely* a red-herring and probably was created through some side-effect by the previous user.

The location of the files (and how to back them up) for a WSL installation on that drive are going to depend on two things:

- Whether the installation(s) was WSL1 or WSL2.
- The distribution that was installed.  While Ubuntu is, in my experience, the most common WSL distribution in use, it could be one of a number of others.  It could also be more than one distribution.

The full-and-complete "right" answer (but probably overkill) would be to:

- Run regedit, navigate to HKEY_USERS
- *File* -> *Load Hive*, navigate to the user's Windows profile on the drive you have obtained (e.g. `D:\Users\username\`), and load the `NTUSER.DAT` in their profile directory.
- Give the hive a name in RegEdit, something like `previoususer`
- Navigate to `HKEY_USERS\previoususer\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss`.
- Any subkeys there should include a `BasePath` with the location of the WSL files (relative to the *original* drive location).

But as I said, that's probably overkill.

Assuming that there was only one WSL distribution installed, and it was Ubuntu, the files will *likely* be in `D:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState`.

If the installation was WSL1, then the filesystem will simply be visible in that directory.  Please note, while it would be okay to access these files on a defunct WSL1 install like this, accessing a live WSL1 filesystem in this way is likely to [corrupt it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/).

If the install was WSL2, then everything is going to be in a virtual HDD named `ext4.vhdx` in that folder.

Accessing the files in `ext4.vhdx` is trickier, since Windows can't mount that virtual disk since it doesn't understand the ext4 filesystem.

You'll need to either:

- Mount the virtual disk in a Linux system using something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37790474/11810933).  Note -- This *might* work from your WSL2 instance, but I haven't tried it.
- Backup an existing WSL on your Windows install with `wsl --export`, then create a new instance with `wsl --import NewDistroName <some_directory> <the_tar_file_from_the_export> --version 2`.  Then copy the `vhdx` file from the old drive over the `vhdx` file in the `<some_directory>` location you created.  Hacky, but it works.
- Wait for the 2021H2 release of Windows 10 that will include the ability to mount these files directly into another WSL instance.  Or run Windows Insider/Preview to get access to this feature now (caveat being that it is a "preview" version with known bugs).

Comment: Having done this (more than once), this is very good advice (+1).  NotTheDr01ds has pretty much steered you to every known way to accomplish this.

Comment: Perfect! I had not even considered that `wsl$\` could be a red herring. It must have been a side effect of me hacking WSL to work in ways that it isn't designed for ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it was a default WSL2 install running Ubuntu, you should find the file `ext4.vhdx` in: `OldDrive:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState`

Create a WSL Ubuntu install in your new system, then do `wsl --shutdown` and copy that `ext4.vhdx` from above to the same location in your new system. You will have an ext4.vhdx there from your new install that you will overwrite.

Note that using `wsl --import`, it is possible to create the `ext4.vhdx` file somewhere non-standard. If that was the case on your old drive, you will need to locate it first.